# How can I pass two commands with all their switches in Windows command prompt or powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to pass a `netstat -t -b 90` command and tell the prompt to simultaneously or successively perform this command to launch network monitor start netmon /autostart.

Answer (score 2):

The `Start-Job` command in PowerShell will do what you want. You'll want to use it in conjunction with `Wait-Job` and `Receive-Job`.

For example:

```
$netstat = Start-Job {netstat -t -b 90}
$ping = Start-Job {ping 192.168.1.1}
Wait-Job $netstat,$ping
Receive-Job $netstat,$ping
```

The first two lines will begin the `netstat` and `ping` jobs, and store the job objects. `Wait-Job` will wait until the two jobs are finished. `Receive-Job` displays the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use start-process, if you're not picky about launching them in a separate window rather than in the background.